# Open google play store app purchase from within app

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

I was watching youtube and i realized there was an ad for an app with install button under the video.

I pressed the button and it popped up play store purchase, similar to in-app purchase of items! Except it wasn't an item but a full app purchase!

I googled this and couldn't find anything, all the clues point to the normal in app purchase rather than the inapp "app" purchase.

My question is, how to pop up play store in a modal window without leaving the app for purchasing another app?
which Android API should I be using?

Thanks

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]

Comment: It is definitely anout programming.  It is the explanation of how to use and which API to use to achieve this.

Comment: i had posted a comment....how did it get deleted ?

Comment: Maybe you can use `android-market-api` [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) to get the data from play store and then display them on the dialog in your app.

Comment: @bjiang That doesn't seem to be the official thing. What's happening here is the Playstore dialogfragment is being shown as an overlay on top of the current app's activity. My guess is that either google is A/B testing these apis and there's no official support for it or these must be internal implementations that haven't been documented well.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that is inner apis and not open for public. You can just first try using `android-market-api`.